# Passing a nil object error

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'v created a notes project in Xcode and I'm using Core Data. I created an entity called 'Note' with a string attribute called 'content'. (used editor/create NSManagedObject subclass to create the note model)

In my prepareForSegue method (in `CreateNotesViewController`) i'm setting my note content property to the TextView content so I can get this note in the `NotesListViewController` and present it.

But I'm getting an error while trying to add this received note to my notes array in `NotesListViewController` telling me that the note is nil...

This is my prepareForSegue method in CreateNotesViewController:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (sender != self.saveButton) return;
    if (self.myTextView.text.length > 0) {

        self.note.content = self.myTextView.text;

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

        // creating a new managed object
        NSManagedObject *newNote = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Note" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        [newNote setValue:self.myTextView.text forKey:@"content"];

        NSError *error = nil;

        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my unwindToList method where I'm trying to add the note to the array and getting the error:

```
- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    CreateNotesViewController *source = (CreateNotesViewController *)[segue sourceViewController];
    Note *recieivedNote = source.note;

    if (recieivedNote != nil && self.editedRow == -1) {
        [self.notes addObject:recieivedNote];
    } else {
        [self.notes replaceObjectAtIndex:self.editedRow withObject:recieivedNote];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Please help me to figure this out, it's the first time i'm using Core Data :/

this is the error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You quite explicitly check to see that the pointer in not nil, and then proceed to use it in the *else* leg.  Almost certainly source.note is nil.

Comment: @HotLicks hi, what that really weird is that is not suppose to be nil...i get the error after typing something and hitting the "save" button

Comment: When you have a nil, trace it back to its source.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm trying :/ I added a breakpoint in the prepareForSegue method of the creating view controller and it is nil...but I don't know why...self.note.content = self.myTextView.text; this line suppose to populate the note property but it doesn't

Comment: Are you sure that line ever gets executed?  And if `self.note` is nil I suspect that the above statement would be a no-op.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm really a beginner so i'm not sure at anything yet :) Too bad you can't take a pick at the project...it's really short

Comment: @HotLicks I can email you the project if you'd like to look at it :)

Comment: If you're a beginner at programming you really shouldn't be working in Objective-C yet.  You won't understand what you're doing and will develop a bunch of bad habits.  Work with C or Java until you have the basic concepts down better.

Comment: @HotLicks I know some Java, still learning it in school. I'm studding cs, so it helped learning Objective-C, but now I'm learning how to work with it :) it's really fun so far, I really want to be good at it, and would love to get any feedback. thanks